# Asp Net Core VSIISExeLauncher.exe Crashing

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, iis-express

When there are multiple project in a solution and VS 2015 does a build.

I have checked the event logs and always see

```
Process was created with commandline '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\ProjectSystem\VSIISExeLauncher.exe" ...  but did not listen on the given port "xxx"
```

but there is another log immediate before/after (in the same second)

```
Process '12120' started successfully and is listening on port 'xxx'.
```

Where the ports are the same number. I have attempted deleting the applicationhost.config in .vs folder and many other workarounds I have found online but it seems that VS 2015 is trying to start two website at the same time and IISExpress crashes.

Comment: Are you using SSL?

Comment: Yes we are using SSL. The whole process works sometimes and on some computers with the exact same source code it work flawlessly.

Comment: Seems like you're missing / have an untristed SSL Certificate. As far as I know its a bug during one of the Updates (Update 2 or Update 3), which cause the certificate not to be installed correctly. Look at my answer below on how to make the IISExpress Certificate trusted

Comment: No, we solved that a while ago and added the cert to our trusted certificates. This is actually the debugger crashing from the IIS express error

Comment: Which `applicationhost.config` did you delete? There are actually two, one in the user folder (`%userprofile%\documents\iisexpress\config\applicationhost.config`) and one in the `.vs/config` folder within your solution folder. Later one is newer, project specific one introduced with VS 2015 iirc

Comment: I have actually deleted the .vs/ and the iisepxress/ applicationhost.config's multiple times with no success.